# Why does my "back to top" button only work when I am at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, 
//  show the button.
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("Button").style.textAlign = "center".display =
      "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Button").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Comment: Providing a working snippet increases chances for receiving a better answer.

Comment: What does 'only work' mean? Does it fail to display? Does it not navigate when clicked? What is the current behaviour? How does it differ from the desired behaviour?

Comment: By the looks of it it should be working, unless there is something else going on

Comment: `"center".display = "block";`   Your adding a property called display to a string, and setting it's value = to block..

Comment: pointless JS only snippet is pointless

Comment: We cannot help you find the issue if you do not provide all the relevant code in a working example that recreates the issue. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)